# I want to send notification to multiple users (that is users of a group) when i send a message in an activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the list of the users and when i send the message, all users in that group receive the message but the notification is not sent. Am using a for each loop to loop through the list of users and send the notification. i am using the same code to send notification (just with some slight modification) from one user to the other. Please what am i doing wrong? Below is my code:

```
// sends notification to respective users as soon as message is sent
    private void sendNotification(final List<String> receivers, final String username , final String message){

        /* for loop to loop through the list of users id in
        the group and send the notification accordingly */
        for(final String id : receivers){

            DatabaseReference tokens  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.TOKENS_REF);
            Query query = tokens.orderByKey().equalTo(id);
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Token token = snapshot.getValue(Token.class);
                        Data data = new Data(admin_uid, R.mipmap.app_logo_round, username+": "+message,
                                getString(R.string.application_name), id);

                        assert token != null;
                        Sender sender = new Sender(data, token.getToken());

                        // apiService object to sendNotification to users
                        apiService.sendNotification(sender)
                                .enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
                                        if(response.code() == 200){
                                            if(response.body().success != 1){
                                                Toast.makeText(GroupMessageActivity.this,"Failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                        // display error message
                                        Toast.makeText(GroupMessageActivity.this,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // display error message
                    Toast.makeText(GroupMessageActivity.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });


        }

    }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient debugger, so you'll have to do much of that yourself and then tell us what happens if you're still stuck. For example: when you run the code in a debugger and place a breakpoint on the first line in `onDataChange`, does it ever get there? If so, can you step into the `for` loop (i.e. are there any `token` values)? If so, does a breakpoint on the first line of `onResponse` get hit?

Comment: ok ....let me try that and get back please.

Comment: @ Frank Van Puffelen, the breakpoint hits the first line in onDataChange and i get this message below and i dont understand please :  DataSnapshot { key = Tokens, value = {upbpNg2QWabSpWS9kU6YIuAJxct1={token=d3VQn_ASn-A:APA91bF6Pn9CcYa_zK8cPkt-RgKftzymm4m9b7Kxbtxwq8FQZnGDyS1KOxoGpwrmvGb9s4iv67dWn92R6ZwRcX56MAYiUIh1XI697ttRQA8csDSZBLOLgAXEd22eB40x0Am5YedrdifV}} }

Comment: If the debugger hits the first line, that means that you're getting data from the database. So in that case the problem is likely in how you parse it/handle the `dataSnapshot`. So keep following the steps in my first comment: can you step into the `for` loop (i.e. are there any `token` values)? If so, does a breakpoint on the first line of `onResponse` get hit?

Comment: Will do that and get back..Thanks

Comment: @ Frank...Thanks for the help..its finally working and notifications are sent.

Comment: Good to hear Ali. Do you feel like posting an answer? Self-answers are quite accepted here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have added that in the section below

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and that was by cleaning my project and rebuilding it.

To do this:

1. locate <kbd>Build</kbd> on the Menu bar, click on it and you will see <kbd>Clean Project</kbd> and <kbd>Rebuild Project</kbd>.
2. Click on <kbd>Clean Project</kbd> and wait patiently for gradle to finish.
3. Now click on <kbd>Rebuild Project</kbd> and it worked for me.

The code I posted above is working fine, but I think android studio was misbehaving. Hope it helps in case someone encounters a similar problem.